# Interactive iterative folder filtering in bash

Tags: linux, bash

Say I have a deep folder structure such as:

```
/home/user1/Pictures/web/flickr/2023/02/02/pic.jpg
```

At every step obviously there are different folders. E.g. at the top there are

```
/etc
/home
/usr
```

and what not. Then under /home there are things like:

```
/home/user1
/home/user2
/home/user3
```

Then under /home/user1 there are things like:

```
/home/user1/Downloads
/home/user1/Pictures
/home/user1/Videos
```

and so on, you get the gist. Is there a way to interactively filter folders to get to a leaf folder or file? E.g. I'd like to do something like:

```
$ vim /
```

then <kbd>Tab</kbd> and have it list all the top level completions (etc, home and usr in the above example). Then if I typed

```
$ vim /h
```

it should display only those containing letter `h` (/home in the above example). If it's the only one, it would complete the single choice, so I'd get:

```
$ vim /home/
```

and then have it list all the choices under /home (user1, user2 and user3 in the above example). Now if I typed 1, it would narrow down to:

```
$ vim /home/user1/
```

since that's the only option that could match.

I know bash has completion, but I'm not sure if there's anything such as this. Any hints?

Comment: I'm not sure how easy it's in `bash` (or if possible at all), but check `fish`. Or probably `zsh` with some plugin maybe. (Thanks to some answers from Stéphane Chazelas on Unix&Linux SE my *impression* is that `zsh` has ambitions to be able to replace everything :) .)

Comment: Sorry, but on my system, this is exactly how bash-filename completion works. Where is your bash behaviour different?

Comment: @LjmDullaart You can type `vim /home/1`, press `<kbd>Tab</kbd>` and it would complete to `vim /home/user1`?

Comment: Ah. I missed that one. No, you need the `u`<tab> before the `1`. Bash completes from left to right, not the first difference. So, in standard `bash` it cannot be done.